# Choosing $2$ paths through $(0,0)$ to show: $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^4}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find $2$ paths through $(0,0)$ to show that
$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^4}$ does not exist.

I only manage to use path $y=x$ but can't find second one. Any thoughts on which path to choose to show that this limit doesn't exist? Thanks!

Comment: Try $x=t^2$, $y=t$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Try $y=0$ and $x=y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$.