# Show the following limit does not exist at $(0,0)$: $xy^2/(x^4 + y^2)$

Tags: limits

This is a math question I'm supposed to do, I know the limit does not exist(it's mentioned in the question) but I can't find any 2 paths that gives me any other answer than 0. Please if you can answer this, help me out
Thanks

Comment: Is the limit complex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing $2$ paths through $(0,0)$ to show: $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^4}$ does not exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852682/choosing-2-paths-through-0-0-to-show-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2)

Comment: @user170231 OP's question has the powers in the denominator reversed. Although they might want to check if they've copied the problem down wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)$ be inside the circle of radius $r$, but not the origin.  Either $y=0$ and $x$ is not, or $x=k\sqrt{|y|}$ for some $k$.  In the first case, the function is $0$.  In the second case, it is
$$\frac{k|y|^{5/2}}{y^2(k^4+1)}\\=\frac k{k^4+1}\sqrt{|y|}$$
Find an upper bound of $c\sqrt r$ for some $c$ that works for all $k$.  Then this approaches 0 as $r\to0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Consider the path through the origin $y=x$, when calculating the limit when $x\to 0$ then $f(x,y)\to 0$, and the second path $y=\sqrt{x}$, then when $x\to 0$ then $f(x,y)\to \frac{1}{2}$.

therefore the limit does not exist

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm gonna try it!